# Is it possible to use diffrent calendars with CalendarView in Android

Tags: android, calendar

I have a use-case where I want to show a calendar to user based on their preference, the default is a `GregorianCalendar`, but the user can select a `ChineseCalendar`, `IslamicCalendar`, `IndianCalendar` etc... and was wondering if the `CalendarView` supports these calendar types.